# xcode mfmailcomposeviewcontroller lock setToRecipients

Tags: iphone, xcode, viewcontroller

I have app that user contact me

The problem is that the users can put any email address, but I want to lock or do something to `setToRecipients` so that user can't make any change in this field.

Here is my code

```
MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"123@abc.com", nil]];
    [composer setSubject:@"subject here"];
    [composer setMessageBody:@"message here" isHTML:NO];
    [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
    [composer release];
}
```

Any help or guide !!

thanx & regards

Answer (score 0):

You can't as `MFMailComposeViewController` does not provide that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

By the look of it, you can't. And the reason is that apple has safety protection to ensure you app doesn't auto send spam emails, in their point of view, it's the user should always have flexibility to choose where the email goes to.